# Why is the Wikileaks site still accessible? How come it hasn't been hacked?

Tags: attacks, webserver, attack-prevention, ddos

Let me get started by saying I think Wikileaks is great, and that their work is invaluable. Background/context for this question: The recent Wikileaks data dump on the CIA. I've visited the site several times over the past few days and have read over it, and the site has been up every time.

Now obviously the CIA doesn't want this information out in the public domain. Additionally, certain governments would be unhappy with this information being out there. In light of this, how is it that the Wikileaks site is still up?

With the hacking capabilities of the CIA having been revealed, how has the site stayed up? Are they not trying to hack it? Why haven't other foreign powers hacked or DDoS attacked it in the past when it's posted information they didn't want public? Surely Wikileaks' security isn't THAT impervious. Or are they just not being attacked?

Comment: Keep in mind that Assange is himself a computer expert, writing deniable encryption for wikileaks. Look up his handle Mendex

Comment: @J.A.K. Keep in mind that the CIA could, for example, inject "voluntary" developers into open-source projects for the only goal to kill that site.

Comment: Well DDoS can be prevented by techniques like Cloudflare does, using Anycast with servers all around the world, so maybe if you can't see a DDoS doesn't mean it's not happening. [They've hold up to 65Gbps DDos attacks](https://blog.cloudflare.com/65gbps-ddos-no-problem/)

Comment: @peterh but surely they're well-screened for such instances...?

Comment: @J.A.K. They could also inject material into the site which could discredit them.

Comment: @Azteca Wow, that's pretty impressive. Gonna go switch all my site's code sources for stuff like jQuery and AngularJS to cloudflare. TX

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon I don't understand. Who should be screened for what? The opensource communities have no way to know if one of the 200 of their committers produced also some "gems" in the code. It is enough to make some "mistake", even if some of them would be discovered, first nobody will be able to know, if it was intentional, and second, a lot of them won't be. See the ssh remote root hole some years ago, probably much more sophisticated attacks could also work.

Comment: @peterh Sorry! Guess I was unclear. I meant for stuff like background working for gov't agencies (although I guess if the gov't wants to inject someone into Wikileaks they can get them a fake ID). Maybe that's feasible?

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon Not into wikileaks, they can inject anybody into mediawiki, gnu libc, linux kernel, apache development, remote admin tools, anywhere. They can do the same into any software of his hosting provider. They can get his certs and cookies by the known backdoors in his mobile phones.

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon The Mossad injected the stuxnet into the Iranian nuclear program on a way, that they had infected a taiwanese network card driver, and provided for it on internal contacts a real microsoft driver signature. This network card driver uploaded a "buggy" firmware into the siemens centrifugas (which was also developed, probably from leaked siemens sources) which destroyed them. And it was the Mossad, having much fewer resources as the CIA.

Comment: @peterh Wasn't the CIA or the No Such Agency (or was it homeland security0 responsible for the bug though? The way I understood it was that the reason that they couldn't get rid of it was because it was EVERYWHERE, and just only was infecting the equipment at the facility, but that's why they could throw all the computers out, get new ones, and they would all be infected again.

Comment: @peterh: injecting a personnel into most open source project  requires years of effort, most people don't get accepted just by submitting one or two patches, but hundreds of high quality patches over many years. And many open source projects wouldn't allow any contributors to become trusted developer outside of the founder company. And once the rogue patch is found, the identity is burned. Why would they do that when every day, hundreds of clueless developers injects vulnerabilities unwittingly? They could much more cost effectively just do a code review to find these existing vulnerabilities.

Comment: You know... *competent* security is actually possible, believe it or not.

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon Cloudflare isn't without its issues. [Cloudbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudbleed) anyone?

Comment: @LieRyan that's why they are called advanced PERSISTENT threats.

Comment: @LieRyan Too closed opensource projects will with time lack of contributors, and so they will be forgotten or forked. As I produce a pull request on the github into anything, it will be nearly always merged.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why haven't other foreign powers hacked or DDoS attacked it in the past when it posted information they didn't want public?

Attacking the Wikileaks website to withhold information is ineffective. The site's availability is just not crucial for making the leaks public.

Instead of only hosting the documents centralized on their web servers, Wikileaks follows a different publication approach. Take the latest [Vault 7 leak](https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/) as an example: The documents were first [released as an encrypted torrent file](https://twitter.com/wikileaks/status/838910359994056704), and the key was only made public one day later. Without revealing what the content actually was, Wikileaks made it less likely that someone would interfere with the publication. Furthermore, that made it possible to download the documents without incriminating yourself - because at the time of the release, you wouldn't know that posessing contents of the file might be illegal. Also note that despite being declared the "largest ever publication of confidential documents on the CIA" (8,761 documents), the torrent is just over 500 MB in size that can be quickly shared across the Internet. And even with an ongoing DDoS attack, it would just be a matter of mailing USB sticks to selected journalists. After all, most people read about the leaks in the news rather than [searching the archive](https://search.wikileaks.org/).

That said, there were indeed [lots](https://twitter.com/wikileaks/status/9609091915718656) [of](https://twitter.com/wikileaks/status/233980974009040897) [DDoS attacks](https://twitter.com/wikileaks/status/809791641867485185) against Wikileaks in the past years. That's why during the attacks around 2010, volunteers have set up [hundreds of mirror sites](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/12/06/world/europe/06wiki.html). But today's attacks are more likely a botnet power demonstration rather than a targeted operation to suppress releases.

Comment: There are also tons of mirrors, on clearnet http, ftp, freenet, etc.